# How to solve "Couldn't save screenshot storage may be in use"

Tags: storage, insufficient-memory, system-error, cache, screenshots

i have been experiencing an issue on my smartphone.Every time i try to save a picture it says"Couldn't save screenshot,storage may be in use"

I already tried to clean the whole cache but it didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i have already fixed  this issue.It is basically a cache problem that i was experiencing,however even if i cleaned that,it didn't work so I got to go a little bit deeper and I found the solution.Very simple
1:Go to settings then application manager

2:Click on Chorme(in my case,the problem was on Google Chrome and Google)

3:Click on Manage Storage ,then on Manage and delete the content

4:Do the same to Google application and the problem will be fixed.

5:Also try cleaning DATA from apps if the text above doesn't work! (VERY USEFUL TOO).

Although it is simple I had a hard time trying to figure out what was wrong,then I noticed that it was not only to clean the cache normally but you also nedded to open its configuration and clean the cache that was in there.Apparently Google Chorme stores a lot of trash and over the time,it might cause some issues. Please if you have other ways to fix this problem,share them here. Let's help others :)[image][image][image]

Learn more at:
https://www.popsci.com/fix-most-common-smartphone-problems/